# adding element in array when array is empty in Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am facing a problem in javascript array...i am using Serversent event in JS. I will be getting few values from server frequently...

My task is to catch all the details and display in drop-down box...

Now the problem is, during the first request, i will getting values seperated by comma..
I have array object in js...i will check if the array is empty, if so, then i will include the values in combo...

code:

```
var varArr = new Array();


//since i am using SSE, i will executing this below part multiple times automaticall when ever server pushes data..

if(!varArr.length){
varArr[0]='somevalue';
//Printing some value in <div>
}
else{
//some task...to print in <div>
}
```

Since i have added some values in array if the array is empty, i am not getting any values printed in div (//Printing some value in ), instead i am getting (//some task...to print in )

Comment: I don't know if it matters because you didn't provide much code, but arrays start at 0 not 1

Comment: i have updated the question at the end...Please help on this

Comment: using jquery to print some value in div. my condition if(!varArr.length) -> returns true if array is empty..and as I enter the condition, i add value in array...But problem is if I dont add any element in array inside the condition, it prints the value in div...Now my code automatically moves to else part

Comment: computers start a zero, not one, but that's probably not the issue...

Comment: updated the post...corrected the index...but problem persists...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yhZHa/2/

still not sure what your problem is

Comment: you might have to provide more code for your problem to make sense

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you mean to do this?

```
var varArr = new Array();
if (varArr.length === 0) {
  varArr.push(somevalue);
  // Printing some value in <div>
} else {
  // Some task...to print in <div>
}
```

Comment: Yes, mistake in my post varArr[0]='somevalue';..but the problem persists in all case...